# Pick autocomplete from http source angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an autocomplete textbox and i searched and got this script

```
.controller('autoCompleteCTRL', function($scope, $rootScope){
    $rootScope.searchItems = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
    ];

    //Sort Array
    $rootScope.searchItems.sort();
    //Define Suggestions List
    $rootScope.suggestions = [];
    //Define Selected Suggestion Item
    $rootScope.selectedIndex = -1;

    //Function To Call On ng-change
    $rootScope.search = function(){
        $rootScope.suggestions = [];
        var myMaxSuggestionListLength = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<$rootScope.searchItems.length; i++){
            var searchItemsSmallLetters = angular.lowercase($rootScope.searchItems[i]);
            var searchTextSmallLetters = angular.lowercase($scope.searchText);
            if( searchItemsSmallLetters.indexOf(searchTextSmallLetters) !== -1){
                $rootScope.suggestions.push(searchItemsSmallLetters);
                myMaxSuggestionListLength += 1;
                if(myMaxSuggestionListLength == 5){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Keep Track Of Search Text Value During The Selection From The Suggestions List  
    $rootScope.$watch('selectedIndex',function(val){
        if(val !== -1) {
            $scope.searchText = $rootScope.suggestions[$rootScope.selectedIndex];
        }
    });


    //Text Field Events
    //Function To Call on ng-keydown
    $rootScope.checkKeyDown = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 40){//down key, increment selectedIndex
            event.preventDefault();
            if($rootScope.selectedIndex+1 !== $rootScope.suggestions.length){
                $rootScope.selectedIndex++;
            }
        }else if(event.keyCode === 38){ //up key, decrement selectedIndex
            event.preventDefault();
            if($rootScope.selectedIndex-1 !== -1){
                $rootScope.selectedIndex--;
            }
        }else if(event.keyCode === 13){ //enter key, empty suggestions array
            event.preventDefault();
            $rootScope.suggestions = [];
        }
    }
    //Function To Call on ng-keyup
    $rootScope.checkKeyUp = function(event){ 
        if(event.keyCode !== 8 || event.keyCode !== 46){//delete or backspace
            if($scope.searchText == ""){
                $rootScope.suggestions = [];
            }
        }
    }
    //======================================

    //List Item Events
    //Function To Call on ng-click
    $rootScope.AssignValueAndHide = function(index){
         $scope.searchText = $rootScope.suggestions[index];
         $rootScope.suggestions=[];
    }
    //======================================

});
```

But it seems the search results are already predefined with `Actionscript,Basic,C++` etc. how do i change the results some i pick it from an http source because i've got a php file which is in json?

Answer (score 0):

you can use $[http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) , **`$http`** is an AngularJS service for reading data from remote servers

```
    .controller('autoCompleteCTRL', function($scope, $rootScope,$http){   

$http.get("json url")
        .then(function(response) {
              $rootScope.searchItems = response.data;
        });
    });
```

Comment: i get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Comment: U r trying to sort an array?

Comment: Show me the Json data?

Comment: [{"item_id":"3","parent_id":"1","shop_id":"1","item":"Burger","quantity":"200"},{"item_id":"8","parent_id":"1","shop_id":"1","item":"Sugar","quantity":"245"}]

Comment: so when the user types something relating to item, results must show up

Comment: You cannot sort object array using .sort property.

Comment: If you want to sort with item in your array , use this
$rootScope.searchItems.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.item > b.last_nom) ? 1 : ((b.item > a.item) ? -1 : 0);} ); use this, instead of $rootScope.searchItems.sort();

Comment: can you please put it into my scirpt? i'm new to angularjs

Comment: Use this http://angularscript.com/simple-autocomplete-directive-angular/, It helps you